# Core Data predicate for finding x days past since date

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have core data model:

```
Book
----
name 
release_date
```

I need to get all books that at least two days passed from their release_date,
And I want to do it with `NSPredicate` (not to load all of the books to memory, and than loop and check)

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"release_date + "48 hours" <= %@", now];
```

Comment: A day does not necessarily have 24 hours (think of daylight saving time transitions).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The predicate will not change the date for you. You should create the appropriate date (based on the current date, and using `NSDateComponents`) and pass that in to the predicate. You can use `<=` in the predicate for filter for older dates.

---

In other words, don't think of the problem as:

```
@"release_date + "48 hours" <= %@", now
```

think of it as:

```
@"release_date <= %@", now - "48 hours"
```

so you problem is just to get the `now - "48 hours"` date to pass to the predicate.

Comment: I don't want to change the date, I want to fetch all those books with at least two days passed from their release_date. I will update the question to be more clear

Comment: I don't mean the predicate won't change the date in the stored data, I mean you need to calculate the appropriate date and pass it to the predicate, because it won't change it during the comparison.

Answer (score 4):

I think you want something like that:

```
NSDate *date2DaysBefore = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-2*24*3600];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"release_date <= %@", date2DaysBefore];
```

Comment: A day does not necessarily have 24 hours (think of daylight saving time transitions).

Comment: It's not a precise answer!! only a hint to a possible solution to his problem. If we want to be precise we should format the date to remove the time components because a book's release date does not contain hours and minutes ...